# Issue with Gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activeadmin

I'm trying to install active admin which I was partly successful with. However, I want to use the '0-6-stable' and not the "1.0.0.pre2" version. When I changed my gem file to reflect my change, I get the following error message:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "formtastic":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      formtastic (~> 2.0) ruby

    formtastic (3.2.0.pre)
```

Now, I've gotten this message before and I would just delete my Gemfile.lock but it doesn't seem like that is working.

Copy of my gem file:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.1'
gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'formtastic',          github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.5'
gem 'railties', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.5'
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.5'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin', branch: '0-6-stable'
#gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
#gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem "fog"
gem "figaro"
gem 'execjs'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'devise'
gem 'searchkick'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end
```

The reason I want to use the most stable version of active admin is because I'm getting `"NoMethodError in Admin::AdminUsersController#index"` when I select "Admin Users" I hoping that using the stable version will correct this issue.

EDIT: The ActiveAdmin Issue: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4249

Comment: Remove github source from `gem 'formtastic',          github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'`, use `gem 'formtastic'`. SOunds like the latest (that would be found in github) versoin of `formtastic` relies on `1.0.0.pre2`.

Comment: @mudasobwa I modified the gem file based on your responce. I also corrected the file based on the feedback I got from running "bundle install". However, still no luck. I'm getting the following eror message `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      jquery-rails (< 3, >= 1.0.0) ruby

    jquery-rails (3.0.0)` I took out the version number and keep `gem 'jquery-rails'` and still no luck

Comment: `gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.5'` ⇒ `gem 'jquery-rails'`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, is the syntax correct? I'm getting the follwoing error message when running bundle install `Gemfile syntax error on line 13: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.5' => gem 'jquery-rails'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `0-6-stable` branch, if you use rails `>= 4.x`, `0-6-stable` works only with rails `<= 3.x`.

This mean's your `Gemfile` need to look like this:
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

```
ruby '2.2.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.5'
gem 'railties', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.5'
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.5'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
#gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
#gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem "fog"
gem "figaro"
gem 'execjs'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'devise'
gem 'searchkick'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end
```

From the ActiveAdmin point of view there is no need to use ransack, inherited_resources and formtastic from github.

Comment: where you find this information? I don't remember coming  across it anywhere in the documentation or on the GitHub page. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

**1:** remove **`Gemfile.lock`**

**2:** Add `gem 'jquery-rails'`

**3:** add `gem 'formtastic'`

**4:** Run `bundle install`

Still if you have any issue in bundle [Github Active Admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/0-6-stable/Gemfile#L16) ,I would like to say go with `rails 3.2`.

Hope this help you !!!

Comment: when I comment out `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin', branch: '0-6-stable'` it works. However, when I un-comment that gem it fails with the following error message: `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "formtastic":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      formtastic (~> 2.0) ruby

    formtastic (3.1.3)`

Comment: OMG, please, try to get the point instead of mindless copypasting solutions. Try to read about how versioning in gem works. All the gems listed *must* be compatible one with each other. You might just remove all versions and run gem build. That will probably suffice.